# display multiple values in page item in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a query that returns more than one value:

```
select mat_cat into :p4_show_mat_cat from mat_req
```

`mat_cat` holds more than one value.

I want to show those values in page item in oracle apex 22.2.

Which page item type should I use for `:p4_show_mat_cat`?

I tried different types of page items, none of them worked.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you would like those values to be displayed, and is it just for display, or can the user toggle selections?

Answer (score 3):

A page item is always a scalar value - that means it holds a single value. For multi-value item types (shuttle, select list, checkbox group, popup LOV) the value of the item is stored as a colon separated list. If you manually populate this item then use the sql function `LISTAGG` [(docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) to convert the rows to a colon separated list of values:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(ename,':') FROM emp;

KING:BLAKE:CLARK:JONES:SCOTT:FORD:SMITH:ALLEN:WARD:MARTIN:TURNER:ADAMS:JAMES:MILLER
```

Apex can do the conversion of rows to a colon separated list using the type "SQL Query (return colon separated value)" - this is possible in computations, item source value, etc

[image]

The API `APEX_STRING` [(docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/APEX_STRING.html) also has several methods that are useful in converting to and from colon separated strings.

The question that you need to answer of course is... *how* should these values be displayed ?